# Find commit in Git Extensions >= 4.0

Tags: git-extensions

From Git Extensions version >= 4.0, I cannot find commit anymore using hash from this filter:

[image: filter git ext]

Is there a way to find again a commit by hash, wihout using git bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found it on Git Extensions.

With `CTRL + SHIFT + G` appears a modal for this pourpose: "Go To Commit".

[image: go to commit]